# Unable to translate Open Graph Stories in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm currently trying to translate an approved Open Graph story in Facebook and I'm unable to do so. Every time I try to translate a phrase I get the following message:

> Translate submission failed.

It happens to any phrase.

**Update**

I notice that If I change the primary language to English, I'm able to translate it to spanish. That's odd tough, because Open Graph stories have to be in english if not mistaken, so that's independent to the app localisation.